# How to access IConfiguration property from Controller in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I am interested how can I access the `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }` from the `controller` ?
Is it possible to do something like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyName"]`

**UPDATE**

I tried with this approach but I am getting `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration'`

```
public class MyController
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

I tried adding `services.Configure<IConfiguration>(Configuration);` in the `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: @KiranChalla That post helped me to do exactly what I need.

Comment: in startup.cs you should try that instead
`services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IConfiguration), Configuration));`

Answer (score 0):

You should use dependency injection to inject it through your controller constructor.

```
public class MyController
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did tried with that one. I am getting the `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration' `.

Comment: You'll need to register it in your container in `Startup.cs` as well then.

Comment: I added update on this one. I tried it, but doesn't seems that I am doing it properly.

Comment: @ChrisSainty should I register it using `AddSingleton`? Please update your answer explaining how to register it.